# error processing package libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0:amd64

Tags: package-management, dpkg

```
dpkg: error processing package libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0:amd64 (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
```

Attempt to remove resulted in following:

```
sudo apt-get remove libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0:amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 6,947 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
dpkg: error processing package libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0:amd64 (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can't seem to remove it or install it.